# Replace error message in ArcObjects .net custom geoprocessing tool

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

I am writing some validation in the updateparameters method of my custom geoprocessing tool. I need to post an error message when specific conditions exists and I would like to include a standard esri error code with my message. I have the logic worked out and my error message posting but I must not be using the error code correctly because no mater what number I use for the error code, it displays as -1.

[image]

I would like it to display error code [427](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp00000021000427).

This is the simplified code setting the error message.

```
 public void UpdateMessages(IArray paramvalues, IGPEnvironmentManager pEnvMgr, IGPMessages Messages)
 {
     Messages.ReplaceError(5, 427, "You're doing it wrong.");
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var gpUtilites = new GPUtilitiesClass();
gpUtilites.SetMessage1Args(esriGPMessageType.esriGPMessageTypeError,427,
parameterValue, parameterPosition, messages);
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanation around this answer?

Comment: I want to draw your attention to the IGPMessageManager interface. It implemented by GPMessageManagerClass and GpUtilitiesClass. I think that is what the author is looking for. For example, it allows to get message by id and use message with custom arguments. Message can have arguments, for example [735](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp00000017000735). I tested it using it error code, and it works as the author wanted. But unfortunately it does not work specifically for 427 message.

Comment: Thats really odd. I can get it to work with id 735 but it does nothing with 427.

Comment: But I was able to get it working with SetMessage2Args and error 605.

Comment: I replaced the ReplaceError method with the following to get my desired results: 
var gpUtilites = new GPUtilitiesClass();                            gpUtilites.SetMessage2Args(esriGPMessageType.esriGPMessageTypeError, 605, outFCName, outLocation, _outFCName.DisplayOrder, Messages);